# `event` object is unaccessible within this.setState() - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Unable to access the `event` object within the this.setState as I am trying to access the event one callback inside the `this.setState`. It throws error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` Any suggestions how to access this?

Note : `getReportType` is getting called when when the value in dropdrown is selected

The following is `Class` part

```
getReportType(event) {
      console.log(event.target.value) //MetricsByContent
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        metricsParams: {
            ...prevState.metricsParams,
            reportType: event.target.value
        }
      }))
    }
```

The following is render() part

```
render() {
      return (
          <div
              <select id="metricsDropDown" className="browser-default" onChange={this.getReportType}>
                <option value="MetricsByContent">Metrics By Content</option>
                <option value="MetricsByUser">Metrics By User</option>
              </select>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: "Unable to access the event object" -> What does this even mean? What is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: How is this function being called? Is `event` defined correctly if you add `console.log(event)` inside the function?

Comment: @RamyaRamanathan: Certainly not the issue here. `event`  has no connection to `this`

Comment: @Prem `event` is very vell "accessible". However, `event.target` is `null`, which is clearly stated in the error message

Comment: Your best bet is to do a `console.log(event)` and see what data it contains

Comment: @RamyaRamanathan: sorry, corrected the comment. I meant, no connection between event and this

Comment: because of `SyntheticEvent`, solution is either store the value in a variable or use `event. persist()`

Comment: Dropdowns can output `event` and `data` I think you should do `getReportType(event, data) { //...}` then `console.log(event)` and `console.log(data)`. Your value might well be in this `data` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event object is cleared by React and if you want to use it in the setState callback, you either make use of `event.persist()` or copy the value in another variable

According to the [`React docs`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)

> The `SyntheticEvent` is pooled. This means that the `SyntheticEvent`
>   object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the
>   event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As
>   such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

```
getReportType(event) {
      event.persist();
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        metricsParams: {
            ...prevState.metricsParams,
            reportType: event.target.value
        }
      }))
    }
```

or

```
getReportType(event) {
      const value = event.target.value;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        metricsParams: {
            ...prevState.metricsParams,
            reportType: value
        }
      }))
    }
```

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I did